# Every time i call this function the old markers are staying back and new markers are appearing is there any way to solve this?

Tags: javascript, loops, here-api

created new linestring for previous polyline so new route is coming every time but markers are staying back! the for loop creates markers at manuver points.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeQ4h.jpg

```
function addManueversToMap(route){
      var svgMarkup = '<svg width="18" height="18" ' +
        'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
        '<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" ' +
          'fill="#1b468d" stroke="white" stroke-width="1"  />' +
        '</svg>',
        dotIcon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup, {anchor: {x:8, y:8}}),

        i,
        j;

      // Add a marker for each maneuver
      for (i = 0;  i < route.leg.length; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0;  j < route.leg[i].maneuver.length; j += 1) {
          // Get the next maneuver.
          var maneuver = route.leg[i].maneuver[j];
          // Add a marker to the maneuvers group
          var marker =  new H.map.Marker({
            lat: maneuver.position.latitude,
            lng: maneuver.position.longitude} ,
            {icon: dotIcon});
          marker.instruction = maneuver.instruction;
          group.addObject(marker);
        }
      }

      group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
        map.setCenter(evt.target.getGeometry());
        openBubble(
           evt.target.getGeometry(), evt.target.instruction);
      }, false);

      // Add the maneuvers group to the map
      map.addObject(group);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove previously added objects from the group.

Just add `group.removeAll()` at the begining of the method `addManueversToMap`.

Also, for better performance you should move code where you create `svgMarkup` and `dotIcon` out of this method.